# Use angular2 trackBy to update

Tags: angular2-template

I have a collection of items and I want to show it in table via ngFor.
In order to improve perfomance I uses trackBy.

My questions are:
1. How can I use trackBy to item update (not only if item added/delete)?
2. How can I catch the event of row update?